# JavaScript runtime error: NetworkError

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

I'm having problems with my web service, I can't use it from a remote place.

this is my code:

```
<script>
$("form").submit(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
var result = new XMLHttpRequest;
var URL="http://www.webservice.nextstagecode.com/checkUser.ashx?user=" + $('#email').val() + "&password=" + $("#pass").val();

result.open("GET", URL,false);
result.send();
var resultString = JSON.parse(result);

var sample = [];

for (var n = 0; n < resultString.length; n++) {
    sample[n] = { respuestalocal: resultString[n].respuesta };
}

if (sample[0].respuesta == 1) {
    $(location).attr('href', 'menu.html');
}
else {
    $("#error").css("text-align", "center").css("font-size", "0.6em").css("color", "red").html("Usuario o clave incorrecta");
}</script>
```

for example this is a `user=prueba@cuenta.com` & `password=prueba` that you can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to make cross-domain AJAX calls, you need to use [JSONP](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/json-and-jsonp/) instead of JSON because of [Same-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

If you're on the same domain, make sure you're sending back the appropriate headers, for json/jsonp these would be:

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

It should be placed at the very beginning of your php file.

Also make sure that the data you're sending back is properly encoded in JSON format by using `json_encode()` function in php.

Answer (score 1):

You've got (at least) two problems I can see:

1. **Same-Origin Policy.** Due to the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you cannot use `XMLHttpRequest` to request data from other domains. If you have control over the other domain and are okay with restricting access to newer browsers, you can use [cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).
2. **Attempting to use `XMLHttpRequest` as a string.**

   ```
   var resultString = JSON.parse(result);
   ```

   treats `result` as a string, but `result` is not a string; it is an `XMLHttpRequest` object. You instead probably meant to use `result.responseText`, which *is* a string.

Comment: I'm using google chrome 27, and I'm the owner of the domain, what should I to change?

Comment: 'cause I don't know what to do

Comment: I'm returning a Json if I do a change I could have problems

Comment: @JosueFranciscoOrellanaVega: The most transparent way (no changes to your JavaScript code) would be to use CORS. That involves some changes on `webservice.nextstagecode.com`; specifically, you'll need to return the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in your responses (see linked Wikipedia page for example). You may need to make sure your server responds with that for `OPTIONS` requests as well.